# k nearest neighbor density estimation

Tags: pattern-recognition

In k nearest neighbor density estimation we calculate the density using following formula[image]

For given 1D sample X={4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14) if k=3, and we do not consider on boundary samples inside the region then density estimation p(X) at X=10 has to be calculated.

Comment: can you type your question here in latex instead of posting a photo of a screen. it would greatly help with readability. I assume that a final year bachelor student should have learned latex by now.

Comment: @sanjab can you please help now?